# How do I show a loading image while script is working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery/ajax/php to log in to my website. When I check this log in functionality to my server then it's take few seconds to check log in details. So I want to show a loading image while it's check the log in details. How Can I show this loading image ?

This loading image I want to use:

```
<img src="images/loading-image.gif"/>
```

**Form:**

```
<div id="success"></div>

<form id="login_process">
<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Username</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="front_username" placeholder="Username" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="front_password" placeholder="Password"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="LogIn" class="submit"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>    
    <td colspan="2">Forgot your password ? Click <a href="forgotpass.php">here.</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**Jquery Code:**

```
<script>
$('#login_process').submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'login_process.php',
data: $(this).serialize(),
dataType: 'json',      

success: function (data) {
   $('#success').html('');
   $.each( data, function( key, value ) {

    if(key !== 'error') {
            $('#success').append('<p>'+value+'</p>');           

    }  
}); 


    if( ! data.error) {     
        $('#hide').hide();              
         setTimeout(function () {
         $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false);        
           window.location.href = "index.php"; 
    },     2000); 
        }

   }
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: @MohitArora Yes when log in button is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, you just need to get the loading-image and show it before making ajax call, when call is done you just hide it.

**html**

```
<img id="loaderAnim" src="images/loading-image.gif"/>
```

**JS**

```
//Hide image on page load
$('#loaderAnim').hide(); 

$('#login_process').submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

$('#loaderAnim').show(); // Show it before making ajax call
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'login_process.php',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',      

    success: function (data) {
        $('#loaderAnim').hide(); // Hide always after every request
        $('#success').html('');
        $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
            if(key !== 'error') {
                $('#success').append('<p>'+value+'</p>');
            }  
        }); 

        if( ! data.error) {     
            $('#hide').hide();              
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false);        
                window.location.href = "index.php"; 
            }, 2000); 
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to your image tag as follows,

```
<img class="img-loading" src="images/loading-image.gif"/>
```

I'm not gonna write the CSS initial hide of the loading image or the positioning of it, hope you can do it your self.

Then easiest is to change you script as follows,

```
<script>
$('#login_process').submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

//SHOW YOUR LOADING IMAGE 
$('.img-loading').show();

$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'login_process.php',
data: $(this).serialize(),
dataType: 'json',      

success: function (data) {
   $('#success').html('');
   $.each( data, function( key, value ) {

    if(key !== 'error') {
            $('#success').append('<p>'+value+'</p>');           

    }  

    //HIDE YOUR LOADING IMAGE 
    $('.img-loading').hide();
}); 


    if( ! data.error) {     
        $('#hide').hide();              
         setTimeout(function () {
         $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false);        
           window.location.href = "index.php"; 
    },     2000); 
        }
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use css to hide the image initially, then modify your code as follows:

HTML:

```
<img class="loading" src="images/loading-image.gif"/>
```

JS:

```
$('#login_process').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.loading').show();
    .....
    ......
    success: function (data) {
        $('.loading').hide();
        ....
});
```